# Is there a FHIR extension for multiple Appointments per Slot

Tags: hl7-fhir

Here's the use case: A clinic has 4 examination rooms, and can thus book a maximum of 4 concurrent Appointments per Slot.  It does not want to schedule each room separately, as the patient will be directed to whichever room is free at any given point in time. (Equivalently, there are at least 4 treatment staff in the office on any given day, but their schedules are maintained separately from the main appointment schedule.)

The FHIR documentation explicitly says "A slot can have more than one appointment allocated to it. A scheduling system may permit multiple allocations up to a specific number of places."

Is there any way to express that in FHIR? An existing extension that adds a "maximumConcurrency" and "currentBookings" parameters to the Slot resource? Anything along those lines?

I've looked at the Argonaut Scheduling Implementation Guide (circa R3, 2020), and it doesn't have anything (what's more, it looks like it only supports one Appointment per Slot).

I've considered just creating multiple Slot resources per actual time-slot, and I may wind up going with that, but it seems inelegant given that the documentation explicitly says Slot should support this use-case.

Comment: Are you sure you want/need to have multiple appointments per Slot? In this scenario, each exam room is scheduled independently (i.e., no appointments need more than one exam room). Therefore, each would have their own Schedule resource, and a Slot can be linked to one and only one Schedule. Thus, I would think you would have four Schedules (which may be identical in terms of the availability they describe), and you would search for open Slots during the scheduling process across those four Schedules.

Comment: After talking to various people about the actual use case, that is probably the solution I am going to go for.  That being said, I'd sort of like to know the answer anyway for other use cases (such as having N treatment staff available and allowing them to switch between patients).

Comment: An answer to how to represent the number of Appointments permitted in a Slot? There is nothing standard for that; defining one or more extensions (perhaps one for `maxRegularAppointments` and one for `maxOverbookAppointments`) seems like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1):

The references go from Appointment to Slot, so on the Slot itself there is no limit on the amount of Appointments that can reference (i.e. be booked for) the Slot. This is for example also used for overbooking a Slot.

If you need to keep track of how many Appointments reference the Slot or the maximum that can be linkeed by just looking at the Slot resource, you will need to create extensions for those values and add them to the Slot. There are no standard extensions for that, and some workflows will take care of it inside their workflow process or for example by checking the Appointments linking to the Slot and making calculations based on that, instead of using extensions. It is up to you to see what would work best for your system, but it is certainly okay to have your own extensions and have multiple Appointments for a Slot.